# Bound method and instance showing same memory location

Tags: python

My understanding is that bound method and class instance are two different objects, so I expect that they should have different memory location. But in the following script, memory location is same for instance method object and instance object. I tried it on different versions and systems but result is same. But more important, is the value in output is memory location or something else? If it is the memory location, how could it be same?

```
class MyClass1:
    def mydef1(self):
        pass
ins1 = MyClass1()
print(ins1.mydef1)
print(ins1)
```

Output

```
PS E:\dev\Python> python.exe .\method_test.py
<bound method MyClass1.mydef1 of <__main__.MyClass1 object at 0x0000019F6CE03DD8>>
<__main__.MyClass1 object at 0x0000019F6CE03DD8>
PS E:\dev\Python>
```

Comment: @dmitryro methods **are objects**, and they live in different memory locations from the instances they are bound to

Comment: You're not reading the output carefully.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes, I got that wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method is not in the same location, you are reading your output incorrectly. The object is at the address `0x0000019F6CE03DD8` in your case, not the bound method.

This example shows that the memory location is different:

```
class MyClass1:
    def mydef1(self):
        pass
ins1 = MyClass1()

print(ins1.mydef1)
print(ins1)

print(hex(id(ins1.mydef1)))
print(hex(id(ins1)))
```

Prints:

```
<bound method MyClass1.mydef1 of <__main__.MyClass1 object at 0x7ffff670a1d0>>
<__main__.MyClass1 object at 0x7ffff670a1d0>
0x7ffff7f87ac8
0x7ffff670a1d0
```

Comment: oops, didn't realize that.